# Clearing text input via useRef doesn't update the form object of react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hook-form

I am working on a form using react-hook-form for React Native, which I want to submit to the server but I am getting stuck when I want to clear the TextInput and update the object as null, instead of that the object itself is not present in the json.

Step 1 - I have a TextInput which I want to clear by pressing a button.

Step 2 - I am doing this by passing the reference of the input to the button.

So the object is - before clearing the input

```
{
  input1: "some random text",
  object2: "random2",
  object3: "random3"
}
```

After pressing the clear button the text input is getting cleared but the form object is now like -

```
{
  object2: "random2",
  object3: "random3"
}
```

input1 object is missing I want it to be there with its value updated to null.

Source code for TextInput

```
<View style={[AuthorizationStyle.authorizationTokenInput]}>
    <Controller control={control} render={({value}) => (
        <TextInput placeholder="Bearer token (optional)" 
            onChangeText={(itemValue) => setValue("bearerToken", itemValue == "" ? null : itemValue)}
            style={[AuthorizationStyle.textInput]}
            ref = {ref}
        />
        )}
        name="bearerToken"
        defaultValue={null}
    />
</View>
```

Source code for clear Button

```
<View style={[AuthorizationStyle.deleteInput]}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => ref.current.value = null}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBackspace} size={22} color="#dc3545" style={[AuthorizationStyle.iconStyle]}/>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Source code for useEffect -

```
let ref = useRef("");
let val = ref.current.value;
useEffect((val) => {
    if(val == "") {
        val = null
    }
    setValue("bearerToken", val)
}, [val])
```

Code is not optimized yet sorry for this raw code but need to handle this first on urgent basis.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`resetField`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/resetfield) function provided by `useForm` for that:

```
const {resetField} = useForm(/* form options */);
```

and use it like

```
onPress={() => resetField('theFieldName')}
```

This will reset the fields value to its defaultValue. You can override that value if you want:

```
onPress={() => resetField('theFieldName', {defaultValue: ''})}
```

Note that the form state should be kept and managed by `react-hook-form` as the single source of truth. There is most likely no need to have it in a separate state or to use additional refs.

Comment: I tried  doing it with your approach. The key is getting removed from the object  but input field still have the text.

Comment: Sorry but your suggestion didn't work @trixn